# why can't access web site using domain name?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have hosted a web site to Windows server 2012 r2. I've bind 83 port to this site.
When I hit site `http://www.example.com` it open IIS services page but when I'm hitting
`http://www.example.com:83` it saying `This site can’t be reached`.

But after making firewall disabled, I can access this site by IP address as `http://0.0.0.0:83`.

**Edited:**

Can access by using domain name when using `port 81`

Comment: Have you configured "A" record on you DNS server or mapped host name with IP in local host file?

Comment: @PankajKapare, I don't have any Idea about local host file. I just put it on IIS server.

Comment: @PankajKapare, does it matter to not allow to acces site? Where this file exists and how can I check for that?

Comment: Go to  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc folder. You will find hosts file over there. Open it notepad and append entry something like this.  www.example.com     x.x.x.x   where x.x.x.x is IP of your server. You need admin access to modify host file.

Comment: @PankajKapare, added domain name and IP still not working.!

Comment: Do you have host name as www.example.com in your IIS binding?

Comment: @PankajKapare, no, but I have also tried that but that was not workable..

Comment: What do you mean by "not workable"?